# asp.net web services returning empty object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, xsd

I have an XSD file which determines the schema by which my engine can communicate to other  plugins (written in different languages, like Delphi). I used the XSD tool provided by .Net to get a C# class out of the XSD file.

The plugins return an XML string which I then de-serialize into an the class generated by the XSD tool.

Everything's fine up till there, however when I pass an array of the class through a web service to the client, the array contains one element, which is fine, but every field in that object is either null or set to its default value.

Any ideas Why this could be happening ?

I also tried sending dummy data instead of retrieving the data from the plugin normally but still the object returned is empty.

This is the Class generated by the XSD tool:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;


/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public class BookingQueryResponse {

    /// <remarks/>
    public int ErrorCode;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ErrorString;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int BookingQueryID;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int DestinationID;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string DestinationName;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="date")]
    public System.DateTime ArrivalDate;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="date")]
    public System.DateTime DepartureDate;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int CurrencyID;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string CurrencyISO;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string CurrencySymbol;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int LangID;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string LangCode;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("HotelQuotePackages")]
    public HotelQuotePackage[] HotelQuotePackages;
}

/// <remarks/>
public class HotelQuotePackage {

    /// <remarks/>
    public string PackageGuid;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string PackageName;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string PluginGuid;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int ResortID;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ResortName;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int HotelID;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string HotelName;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int HotelRatingID;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string HotelRatingName;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string HotelNarrative;

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.Double MapLongitude;

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.Double MapLatitude;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string HotelRemark;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string OfferText;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("HotelRoomQuotes")]
    public HotelRoomQuote[] HotelRoomQuotes;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("HotelImages")]
    public HotelMediaImage[] HotelImages;
}

/// <remarks/>
public class HotelRoomQuote {

    /// <remarks/>
    public int RoomNumber;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("RoomQuotes")]
    public RoomQuote[] RoomQuotes;
}

/// <remarks/>
public class RoomQuote {

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Guid;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int AdultPax;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int ChildPax;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int InfantPax;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string RoomTypeName;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string RoomTypeDesc;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int BoardBasisID;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string BoardBasisName;

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.Double CostForStay;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string Remarks;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("DayRates")]
    public DayRate[] DayRates;
}

/// <remarks/>
public class DayRate {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="date")]
    public System.DateTime Date;

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.Double Rate;
}

/// <remarks/>
public class HotelMediaImage {

    /// <remarks/>
    public string HotelImage;

    /// <remarks/>
    public int ImageTypeID;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ImageType;
}
```

and just for testing purposes the web Service all I did is this:

```
return return new BookingQueryResponse[1] { new BookingQueryResponse() { ArrivalDate = DateTime.Now.Date, DestinationName = "Malta" } };
```

Comment: it sounds like a mismatch in the xml and the types... hard to tell without specifics though (i.e. both C# and xml)

Comment: have a look at your objects namespace (not c# namespace but xml namespace designated by the attribute XmlType) in your generated class and in your xml file, they must match !

Comment: @Marc Gravell I editied the question to include the c# class generated if it helps.

Comment: @Jonny and what **exactly** is that service meant to return, in xml or xsd terms?

Comment: the service should return an array of BookingQueryResponse[]. The plugins give me an XML string with the data required but that's not the problem the problem is when passing the array through the web service.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the XSD.  As your classes look fine, my initial educated guess is that its a type (namespace) mismatch between your XSD and your C# namespace.